# asp.net file upload problem

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I`m using vs2008. I added a webform with the following code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    upload image:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FUImage" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnUpload" runat="server" Text="Add" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
```

and in cs file is nothing, except default pageload handler that is empty.

I run webapplication, , choosing a jpg file to upload, clicking add new button and see internet explorer can`t show the page specified message.

Comment: Have you got friendly error messages on in IE? this sounds like a classic case of internet explorer hiding a more useful error message. For what its worth if I run that code for an app I get no problems. do you get the same problem if you don't select a file? Is the file you are choosing particularly big (there are configurable upload size limits)...

Comment: Thanks, Chris, it was filesize. Just didn`t noticed file was too big. You gave me that tip, works fine now. If you post an answer I`ll mark it as answer.

Comment: Glad to have helped. I've put an answer and got some doc references as well so the answer would be a bit more useful (sounds like you've sorted it but for future visitors to the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET can limit the size of requests to the server which obviously limits the maximum size of uploadable files.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx explains the appropriate web.config attribute, in particular the maxRequestLength attribtue.

Answer (score 0):

Chris's answer is great but if anyone stumbles across this who is on IIS7, you'll need to add these lines instead:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength=”500000000″ />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
<system.webServer>
```

This allows file uploads of up to 500 Meg.  This takes effect immediately upon saving web.config.  No need to restart IIS.